# When I call the following method, Firebase continuously updates in increments of 5 instead of just sending one update. Why is this?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase as my backend and I am trying to increase a the number that is currently being held in the database by 5. However, when it is called, the database adds 5 over and over again, so the score goes from 5 to 10 to 15... this is repeated until the app crashes.

Why is this happening?

```
func changeUserRewardsScore() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "default")").document("score")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("There was an issue retrieving data from Firestore. \(e)")
            }
            else {
                if let data = querySnapshot?.data() {
                    let myArray = Array(data.values)
                    let userScore = "\(myArray[0])"
                    print("userScore = \(userScore)")
                    self.writeUserScore(score: userScore)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func writeUserScore(score: String) {
        var myScore = 0
        if localData.rewards.freeCookieInCart == true  && score == "50" {
            myScore = 0
        }
        else {
            myScore = Int(score)!+5
        }
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "default")").document("score").setData(["score":myScore]) {
            (error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("There was an issue saving data to firestore, \(e)")
            } else {
                print("Successfully saved data.")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document listener, when triggered, writes back to the same document that triggered it, so it triggers again with the result of that change.  Which starts the whole cycle over again.

It's not clear to me what you expect to happen instead, but if you just want to get the value of the document once, then update it, you should use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()` as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).  Either that, or set up some state in your object that indicates to your listener when it shouldn't update the document again.